# Separating Dataframes in Python to train, test, and graph the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to graph the date on the x-axis and the opening stock price on the y-axis of one stock specifically and then I would like to train, test, split the data, but I need the data separated from this huge dataframe first.
[Reference to my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m34gW.png)

And now I am trying to change "st = stock_final.query("Name == 'AMZN'")" to instead check my user argument string called 'ticker' but I do not know how to implement to check the Name ticker with this query function check that we made? Any advice?

Comment: sklearn has some nice functions for this. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 2):

I assume the date column is the index, if that not the case, I recommend to make the date column the index.

So you can perform some 'operations' on the dataframe to get a new dataframe which only will have the information you need.

Since you only want a single stock, you can use the dataframe function query to select the stock you want based on his name in the 'Name' column and then you select the columns you want based on their name, for example

```
df = df.query("Name == 'AAIT'")
df = df[['Open', 'Name']]
```

Or if you don't need the Name column anymore in the dataframe

```
df = df['Open']
```

And this new dataframe will have the date in the index and the open value based on the stock you select, now you can graph this easily

Here is the link to the query function in pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html?highlight=query#pandas.DataFrame.query

Comment: What would I make x = date and y= open stock price equal to in the 'stock_final.plot(x= , y= )' with your example for df?

Comment: Again assuming the Date column is the index and you are usin the function DataFrame.plot, you only have to specify 'y'. For example: stock_final.plot(y='Open' )

Comment: Okay, thank you. How would I remove the 'Name' column completely to train the data after I extract the information I need from a certain stock

Comment: You can do df = df['the_column_that_i_need'] or use the drop function df.drop(columns=['Name', 'other']) and so on

Comment: I am trying to change  "st = stock_final.query("Name == 'AMZN'")" to instead check my string or input from a function called 'ticker' but I do not know how to implement to check the Name ticker with this query function check that we made? Any advice?

Comment: Hi, my advice is to open a new question , where you can share you code and we can have a better understanding of the problem, i will be checking the question under this tags

Comment: Hi, I just posted a new question referencing my problem

Comment: Ok, good, i already put some answer there.If the answer here in this question work for you, it will be nice if you select the answer, thank you.